# Collecting output from az vm run-command when using no-wait

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I've got to run a script on a large number of VMs and collect the output of the script. Running the process synchronously takes a long time so I was wondering if there's a way to run it asynchronously and still collect the output from each run.

Comment: The main options for _local_ parallel execution in PowerShell are: In [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), `ForEach-Object -Parallel` and `Start-ThreadJob`. In _Windows PowerShell_, `Start-Job` (though you can and should install `Start-ThreadJob` there on demand). Parallelism in _remote_ execution is built into the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet, if you pass it _multiple_ computers / sessions to target.

Answer (score 0):

> Collecting output from az vm run-command when using no-wait.

Thanks to `mklement0` for suggesting the same.

I have used below `PowerShell` script to retrieves information about `Azure VMs` in a specific resource group and exports the details to a `CSV` file with `Start-Job`.

1. The script block is passed to the `Start-Job` cmdlet, which starts the script as a background job.
2. The `Wait-Job` cmdlet is used to wait for the job to complete before proceeding.
3. The `Receive-Job` cmdlet retrieves the output generated by the job, if any.

```
#Define the script block for the job
$scriptBlock = {
    $resourceGroupName = "Identity-Resources"
    $vmList = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
    $vmInfoArray = @()
    foreach ($vm in $vmList) {
        $vmInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $vm.Name
            ResourceGroup = $vm.ResourceGroupName
            Location = $vm.Location
            OSType = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType
            VMSize = $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize
        }
        $vmInfoArray += $vmInfo
    }
    $csvFilePath = "/home/vallepu/File.csv"
    $vmInfoArray | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation
    Write-Host "VM information exported to $csvFilePath"
}
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
Wait-Job -Job $job
$output = Receive-Job -Job $job
```

**Output:**

Once the above code is run, the `VM` information is successfully exported to an `Excel` file.

[image]